# Laravel validation - how add if statement

Tags: php, laravel

I am beginner in Laravel. I need validation to my project. I use Laravel 8.
I have this code in TaskRequest:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'speed_number' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
            'order_number' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
            'address_from' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
            'address_to' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],

            'carrier_name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
            'carrier_nip' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
            'carrier_street' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
            'carrier_email' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
            'carrier_phone' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
            'carrier_postal_code' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
            'carrier_city' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
        ];
    }
```

I need something like this:

```
public function rules()
        {
            return [
                'speed_number' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
                'order_number' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
                'address_from' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
                'address_to' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
    
if($company == true){


                'carrier_name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
                'carrier_nip' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
                'carrier_street' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
                'carrier_email' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
                'carrier_phone' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
                'carrier_postal_code' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
                'carrier_city' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
}


            ];
        }
```

(I need add if statement in request validation code). How can I make it?

Please help me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you're looking for the `required_if` rule. See the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-required-if

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'speed_number' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
        // ... and other rules ...
        'carrier_name' => ['required_if:company,1', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
        // ... and other rules ...
    ];
}
```

Comment: Isn't this only applicable when `company` is also in the request? Which it doesn't seem to be in the example provided?

Comment: I would assume that's what OP meant.

Comment: I have parametr in my request: transport_type. If this == 1 then I need additional validation: 'carrier_name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
                'carrier_nip' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
                'carrier_street' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
                'carrier_email' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
                'carrier_phone' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
                'carrier_postal_code' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255']...

Comment: @jkloip - Exactly. For all of those attributes, use `required_if:transport_type,1` instead of simply `required`.

Answer (score 1):

You need use the [Rule::requiredIf](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-required-if)

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

'carrier_name' => [
    Rule::requiredif(function () use ($company) {
        return $company == true ? true : false;
    }),
    'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Since from the question it's not clear if `company` is in the request.

If it is not you could just return different values based on `$company`

```
public function rules() {
 if ($company) {
  // return rules for when company exists
 } else {
  // return rules for when company does not exist
 }
}
```

If company is in the request, you should take a look at the `required_if` validation Laravel provides. [Laravel Docs - Required if](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-required-if)

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient way to do it would be this one:

```html
        $rules =  [
            'speed_number' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
            'order_number' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
            'address_from' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
            'address_to' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
            'data_start' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:60'],
            'data_finish' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:60'],
            'transport_type'  => 'required'
        ] + ($request->carrier)->map(function ($attr, $key){
            return [
                "carrier.$key" => [Rule::requiredIf($request->transport_type == 2),'min:3', 'max:255'],
            ];
        })->toArray();

        Validator::make($request->all(),  $rules)->validate();
```